# How to pass single-value lists for Columndatasource on Bokeh? Plot is no longer rendering

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

I'm trying to pass multiple plot information through source, but the columns have different lengths. When I plot 1 line, it works fine, but when I changed the code to work for multiple, the plot no longer renders at all.

I have defined my source as:

`source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x1=[], y1=[], x2=[], y2=[], x3=[], y3=[]))`

and my figure and line are:

`p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", title="", sizing_mode="fixed", height = 500, width = 900)`

`p.line(x ="x1"[0], y="y1"[0], source=source)`

I would like to eventually be able to plot multiple lines on this figure, but each might have a different amount of values, so as ColumnDataSource only works with columns of the same length, I have put the columns in single-value lists:
From my update() function.

```
source.data = dict(
    x1=[df1['Time']],
    y1=[df1['Value']],
    
    x2=[df2['Time']],
    y2=[df2['Value']],

    x3=[df3['Time']],
    y3=[df3['Value']],
    )
```

*I changed the df names for the question.*

I'm not sure how relevant it is, but the data is 2 columns, many rows of this:

```
54231  2020-12-04 23:54:31.863000+00:00.
```

My thought is that I could take the first item of the dictionary (on p.line) and it would simply use the data from there, but it will no longer render, does anyone have any idea?

Please let me know if I am missing information here that you need to guide me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the plot no longer rendering because you're only supplying 1 data point per line, and you need at least 2 points to draw a line?

Comment: Hi Cameron, it shouldn't be.

I pass them all as single-value lists, and typing source.data['x1'][0] in the console will return the correct number of rows, not just one data point. I assumed that would have the same effect in p.line().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to plot multiple lines with different number of points, then you have two options:

- use separate calls to `line` each line, using a separate CDS for each line (that individually have columns of all the same length)
- use [`multi_line`](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#multiple-lines) which can accept a "list of lists" (or arrays) to draw mulitple lines at once (the sub-lists or sub-arrays *can* have different lengths).

  ```py
  source.data = dict(xs=[[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 6, 6]], 
                      ys=[[2, 1, 4], [4, 7, 8, 5]])
  p.multi_line('xs', 'ys', source=source)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me, that your problem stems from this line:

```
p.line(x="x1"[0], y="y1"[0], source=source)
```

`x="x1"[0]` is not doing `x = "the first value from x1"`, what it is actually doing is this: `x="x"` because you're just slicing the string `"x1"` for the first (zeroth) element, which is the substring `"x"`.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense and could be the issue - what would you recommend in order to fix this though?

Comment: If you want to show a subset of data for a line plot, I think you'll need to build a separate source with that subset of data that you want to display.